# Joomla plugin creation. Upload car w/ pics and details

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I want to create a plugin and eventually template where a site acts like a car dealership website.

Basically all the functionality I want is to be able to upload multiple images, then have some drop down boxes with make/model etc and a description box.

I am ok with PHP, eager to keep learning but would very much like to complete this task using joomla.

I've checked out the Joomla! docs and it seems well documented, I'm just not sure where to start. I've read basic plugin tutorials and I understand them fine.

some useful links which I guess will come in handy for me? (correct me if I'm wrong)

JForms classes: http://docs.joomla.org/JForm/1.6

also to insert the entered info in the DB I should use this (?):http://docs.joomla.org/JDatabaseMySQL::insertObject/1.6

also see: http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial%3aPlugins

Any insight would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have enough bandwidth, because uploading a car isn't gentle on the servers. haha /joke

Answer (score 2):

Joe you are the nth person to ask this type of question on SO about Joomla. If you are interested in developing this then I suggest you familiarise yourself with the different types of "plugins", if you will, for Joomla. What is required to do such a thing in Joomla is called a component.

Have a look at this tutorial http://www.joomladevuser.com/tutorials/components, it explains the basics of using the Joomla MVC framework.